# Cannot connect to MS Database with java

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

When attempting to open a connection to a database it fails giving me a NullPointerException. This happens when it is trying to get the connection on the con = DriverManager.getConnection(url); line. It goes from this line to the catch exception. What is the correct way?

```
    public void openDatabase () {
    url = "jdbc:odbc:student";              

    try{                                    
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        txtOutput.setText("Database " + url + " is connected\n");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        txtOutput.setText("Problems connecting to " + url + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note i have created a driver using ODBC

Comment: JDBC/ODBC is no longer supported (and issues between 32 and 64 bit environments makes it a mess) and you should consider using a dedicated JDBC driver like [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html)

Comment: Your connection URL is almost certainly wrong.  [See here](https://www.easysoft.com/applications/microsoft-access/jdbc-odbc.html) for how to connect to Access with JDBC.

Comment: Advice: (almost) always print the stack trace of the exception: `e.printStackTrace();` - first source about what went wrong where! (log it for production code, if you don't want it printed)

Comment: I'm still getting a nullpointerexception and when debugging when it passes over the con line it then skips the rest of the method and says null for the con variable             url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/user/Desktop/POS.accdb";
        try{
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);        
          stmt = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connected");
        }

Comment: Try changing the C path to double forward-slashes: `url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\POS.accdb"`. Also check for the  jdbc class prior to connection in `try/catch` block: `Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");`